# Get the id details from an array which was extracted from another array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array that stores Ids as a wishlist of a user.

```
favoriteList:[458215,856254]
```

I have a main array which has details of all ids

```
results":[
      {
         "popularity":708.802,
         "vote_count":931,
         "video":false,
         "poster_path":"\/8WUVHemHFH2ZIP6NWkwlHWsyrEL.jpg",
         "id":338762,
         "adult":false,
         "backdrop_path":"\/ocUrMYbdjknu2TwzMHKT9PBBQRw.jpg",
         "original_language":"en",
         "original_title":"Bloodshot",
         "genre_ids":[
            28,
            878
         ]
      },
      {
         "popularity":719.623,
         "vote_count":2730,
         "video":false,
         "poster_path":"\/xBHvZcjRiWyobQ9kxBhO6B2dtRI.jpg",
         "id":419704,
         "adult":false,
         "backdrop_path":"\/5BwqwxMEjeFtdknRV792Svo0K1v.jpg",
         "original_language":"en",
         "original_title":"Ad Astra",
         "genre_ids":[
            18,
            878
         ]
      },..... and so on
```

when the user clicks on his wishlist section, I'm trying to display the user's selected id's poster path. 
To achieve this, I wrote the code below.

```
 const showFavorites = () =>{
        if(favoriteList && movies){
           return  _.forEach(favoriteList,(data)=>{
                let favorite = _.find(movies.data.results,(favoritemovie)=>{
                     if(favoritemovie.id == data){
                         return(
                             <>
                                <CardGrid image={image_url+favoritemovie.poster_path}/>
                             </>
                         )
                     }
                });
            })
            }
        }
```

the above code returns the id's on the screen.

Actual Output:

```
458215856254
```

expected output must be the outcome of below component

```
<CardGrid image={image_url+favoritemovie.poster_path}/>
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

BTW, I'm using the lodash's foreach and find in that function.

EDIT:
I changed the code as below

```
 const showFavorites = () =>{
        if(favoriteList && movies){
            return (
                <>
                 {
                    movies.data.results.map((movie,index)=>{
                            _.forEach(favoriteList,(data)=>{
                            if(movie.id == data){
                                return(
                                    <>
                                        <CardGrid image={image_url+movie.poster_path}/>
                                    </>
                                )
                            }
                        });
                    })
                 }
            </>)
        }
    }
```

this time I see a blank page. I don't understand what I'missing

Comment: Are you sure the outcome of `<CardGrid image={image_url+favoritemovie.poster_path}/>` is not `458215856254`?

Comment: Yes! this component is already used in another jsx file and it is working fine there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lodash's `_.forEach()` returns the original collection, that is `[458215,856254]`, which stringifies to `458215856254` (in React).

You should always return a value in the map callbacks.

You can use native Array `map` method to iterate and return the results instead of lodash.

Comment: @SyedPasha, you're welcome. If your problem is solved, please select the best answer to mark this topic as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The expected outcome is a string. But the parameter to return statement is not. You may have to enclose in quotes the string part with proper concatenation with the variables to be fed to string.

Comment: you mean I need to tweak the way of returning? Also, I updated my question with a edit in which I slightly changed the way to return the component

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tigran for the explanation. I fixed it by tweaking the code as below

```
const showFavorites = () =>{
            return (
                <>
                   <h3> Your Wish list</h3>
                    <hr/>
                <WishList>
                 {
                     movies.data.results.map((movie,index)=>{
                            const list = _.filter(favoriteList,(data)=>{
                            return  data == movie.id;
                        });
                        if(list == movie.id){
                            return(
                                <>
                                    <CardGrid image={image_url+movie.poster_path}/>
                                </>
                            )
                        }
                    }) 
                 }
                 </WishList>
            </>)
}
```